# getting the original url from http response

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have this function that reads a csv file that contains a list of url.
For every line I do a get request to the current url to read the response header.

```
function readCSV(csv) {
  var lines = csv.split("\n");
  var table = lines.map((line) => line.split(","));
  var requests = table.map((row) =>
    request({
      method: "GET",
      uri: "https://www." + row[1],
      resolveWithFullResponse: true,
    })
    .catch((err) => null) // Errors are ignored and resolved as `null`
  );

  return Promise.all(requests)
    .then((responses) => {
    
      responses.forEach((response) => {
        if(response === null) return; // If the response is null, skip it

        // ... handle successful responses here
        var hrds = response.headers;
        //console.log(hrds.url)
        console.log(hrds['content-security-policy'])
        console.log(hrds['x-frame-options'])

      });
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
}
```

I would like to do something like: `console.log(hrds.url)` to see the url that sent me the response. If I try to print `hrds.url` it gives me undefined.

EDIT:
I tried `response.url` but it prints blank line

Answer (score 0):

According to [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/url) you can get the URL from the response it self.

```
response.url
```

Comment: can you `console.log(response)` and share here ?

Comment: I can't post it, it prints all the header and body, but the string is to long even if i use only one url.